# Iframes converted to image tags in TinyMCE inline mode

Tags: tinymce

I have a content management system that uses TinyMCE to edit text, and I am using the `inline` option. The issue I have is when the content contains an iframe - when TinyMCE is initialised, it converts the iframes to an image tag:

`<img data-mce-p-allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" data-mce-p-frameborder="0" data-mce-p-src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/xxxxx" width="560" height="315" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7" data-mce-object="iframe" class="mce-object mce-object-iframe" data-mce-src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7">`

I then need to get the edited HTML to save to the server. [The docs](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/demo/inline/) for this functionality give no suggestion on how to do this, so currently I use jQuery to just get the HTML content of the element the TinyMCE editor was initialised on, however this contains the image tag instead of the original iframe, which is what then gets saved.

Is there a better way to get the HTML from n inline TinyMCE instance, or change how TinyMCE displays iframes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a TinyMCE Fiddle that shows TinyMCE running inline with an iFrame in the content.  When I use `getContent()` to extract the content it just shows as an iFrame.

http://fiddle.tinymce.com/rkgaab

As a rule of thumb I would not use jQuery to try to get the raw HTML as TinyMCE does a variety of things to accommodate for how inline editing works.  The `getContent()` API is documented here:

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/api/tinymce/tinymce.editor/#getcontent

Comment: Thank you - seems obvious now, when I originally wrote this the editor had been destroyed by the time I blurred out of it and I didn't think you could use getContent() on it. Weirdly the iframes in your fiddle didn't get converted to images like mine do - but regardless the issue is sorted